# Media Player Classic creating folder

Tags: windows-registry, media-player-classic

Whenever I open a file in Media Player Classic it creates a new folder "Media Player Classic" under the folder of the file I opened.  Originally it was putting a playlist in that folder, "default.mpcpl", but I found that if you open the playlist (Ctrl+7) and right-click the playlist, there is an option "Remember items", unchecking that will prevent MPC from creating this playlist.  I was hopeful that without the auto-generated playlist MPC would have no reason to create the folder.  Wrong.  Now the folder is empty, but I still have to follow MPC around deleting all these blank folders.

I use Media Player Classic on several of my computers so I think I just screwed up some variable somewhere somehow regarding where it stores playlists or something, but I can't figure out what it is, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling to little avail.  Which makes me think it might be in the registry.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having this problem and I used Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to investigate what registry values were being queried right before Media Player Classic created the folder.  Turns out it was looking at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\AppData, and for some reason on my system this registry value was present but blank.  I corrected the registry entry to be "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming" (this is on Windows 7 x64) and now Media Player Classic creates the folder in that directory rather than wherever the media file is being opened.

Hope this helps, good luck!